# how to put value of the upper row in the bottom rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
+-----+------------+
| id  |    name    |
|-----|------------|
|  1  |     ali    |
|-----|------------|
|  2  |            |
|-----|------------|
|  3  |            |
|-----|------------|
|  4  |    peter   |
|-----|------------|
|  5  |            |
+-----+------------+
```

I want to put value of upper row the bottom rows. *(If the bottom row was empty)*. Some thing like this:

```
+-----+------------+
| id  |    name    |
|-----|------------|
|  1  |     ali    |
|-----|------------|
|  2  |     ali    |
|-----|------------|
|  3  |     ali    |
|-----|------------|
|  4  |    peter   |
|-----|------------|
|  5  |    peter   |
+-----+------------+
```

Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
update t
    set name = (case when name is not null
                     then @name := name
                     else @name
                end)
    order by id;
```

It seems like the easiest method using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use something like this:

```
update t
set name=case 
           when name is null then (select name 
                                   from (select * from t) it 
                                   where it.id<t.id and it.name is not null 
                                   order by id desc
                                   limit 1)
           else name
         end
```

You can see it in action [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4797b/1), but it should be pretty self evident how it works. The only funny thing is that inner `select`, that's to work around an absurd limitation of MySql where it won't let you select from the table you're updating.

Comment: wow, how did you write that quickly !? I'm working on it for 2 days ! :) anyway thanks buddy

Comment: It's the most literal way of putting your problem in SQL terms, there isn't much subtlety to it. Which is not to say it's inefficient, it makes full use of any existing indices.

Comment: I thought that I know sql, then I think that really I don't know sql.

Answer (score 1):

e.g.:

```
UPDATE my_table a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MAX(y.name) new_name 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.id <= x.id 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id SET a.name = b.new_name;
```

or

```
UPDATE my_table a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN name IS NULL THEN @name ELSE @name:=name END new_name 
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @name:=NULL) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY id
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id
   SET a.name = b.new_name;
```

Comment: Thanks pal, the first worked correctly (i'm not check second yet). I don't know really do you think about what that you can write something like this.